# How to make every page have swipe method by using loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm newbie here. I was try to make every single page have a swipe method for jQuery mobile site as below:

```
$("#page1").swipeleft(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
        transition: "slide"
    });
});
$("#page2").swipeleft(function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page3", {
        transition: "slide"
    });
});
```

when i try to make a loop like this it doesn't work.

```
var i = 1;
if(i <= 3;) {
    $("#page" + i).swipeleft(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page" + (i + 1), {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });
};
```

something missing for my code?

updated: tried this code but seem doesn't work

```
for (var i = 1; i<=3; i++) {
    $("#page"+i).swipeleft(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page"+(i+1), {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });
}
```

here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/lansinz/FHnp6/1/

Comment: Why is there a `;` after `i <= 3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually seem to a loop in your code. Try the following

```
//Create a loop for pages 1 to 3
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    //When page is 'swiped' call the nextPage() function
    $('#page' + i).on('swipeleft', nextPage);
}

function nextPage(event) {
    //Get the ID attribute of the element swiped
    var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
    //Get the number at the end of the elements ID (to work out the page number)
    var pageNo = parseInt(id.substr(4), 10);
    //Call the changePage function, increasing the page number by one
    $.mobile.changePage($('#page' + (pageNo + 1)), {
        transition: 'slide'
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Dracs/eZgUg/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply...but seem it doesn't work in my code. here is my code: jsfiddle.net/lansinz/FHnp6/1

Comment: @user2218063 I haven't use jQuery Mobile before so I wasn't too sure on it. I've forked your jsFiddle and and tested the updated code in my answer on my Nexus 7 and it is working for me.

Comment: thanks again @Dracs its work =D. but the code was little complicated for me to understand.><

Comment: @Daniel I've added some comments in to better explain what the code is doing. If there's a specific part your still having difficulty understanding let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Or the old school way of doing it with lengthy code :)

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page1', function(){
    $( "#page1" ).on( 'swipeleft', function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('#page2');
    });
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '#page2', function(){
    $( "#page2" ).on( 'swipeleft', function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('#page3');
    });

    $( "#page2" ).on( 'swiperight', function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('#page1');
    });
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '#page3', function(){
    $( "#page3" ).on( 'swiperight', function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('#page2');
    });
});
```

Comment: i was plan to do that but i will having big issue for 100 pages to key in one by one.